# Microsoft Teams Bot - Writing to a bot returns error message

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've created a bot based on the following sample:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot

Everything looks well so far and worked in my first bot. But with my second bot I've created when I start a conversation with the bot, I get a "**Failed to send**" error in Microsoft Teams on my desktop.

When I use teams in the web I can see in the dev tools the following error message for the request:
https://emea.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/threads

Error:
`One or more of the user ids provided are not valid.`

I'm lost on what could be wrong. Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using two chatbot's with same endpoint parallelly  in same channel? Could you please provide bot id to so that this issue can be forwarded to bot framework team.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT no it is just one. What exactly do you mean by "bot id"?
Here the Microsoft App Id: 375148f4-fe75-400a-9316-1638b993ba39

Comment: Did the below step helped? @stefan

Comment: @Manish-MSFT Teams Channel is configured and Running. The Issue is still here.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT The issue had todo with the credentials of the app which where somehow not correct in the bot channel registration. no idea how I could fail multiple times on this. But it is working fine now. So if you face this kind of strange id error: Check the setup on azure again!

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same error after creating a second bot for testing and realized I had forgotten to setup the Teams channel in Azure configuration.

So double-check that the Microsoft Teams channel is running:

[image]